# Long delay on main thread

Tags: android, stack-trace

I am capturing one of my screen transitions that cause a long delay resulting in lost frames. I am having trouble figuring out where the problem code is. This is my stack trace. What does android.os.MessageQueue.next() mean ?

[image]

trace top

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's how the system is communicating with the app. It's a message-passing system. It doesn't look like it's taking up much of your execution time (and it shouldn't be). Could you post the trace from the top?

Comment: MessageQueue is system level call that display messages. It probably doesn't cause your application delayed. There must be some operation you are doing on main thread. You have to move that out of main thread to to a new thread.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean the top of the window. I meant from the parent in the detailed view.